# Trying to get socket from wininet HTTP connection

Tags: c, sockets, windows-7, wininet

We have a legacy application that implements an SSL tunnel over Web proxies. It uses the wininet API and it worked fine for years on XP, but now it fails on Windows 7. I've tried to isolate the code and made a small program to reproduce the problem. It's a small C program compiled with MSVC 9. See below.

On Windows 7, once connected to the proxy (status code 200), I just cannot get the socket descriptor from the API. All I get is an INVALID_SOCKET, even though all wininet functions returned successfully and GetLastError() returned 0.

On the XP machine, all works fine and the returned socket is valid.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char *_connect()
{
    HINTERNET hOpen = 0;
    HINTERNET hConnect = 0;
    HINTERNET hRequest = 0;
    int remotePort = 443;
    const char *remoteHost = "a.b.c.d"; // Cannot disclose
    hOpen = InternetOpen("wininet-test", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!hOpen) return "InternetOpen";
    hConnect = InternetConnect(hOpen, remoteHost, remotePort, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if (!hConnect) return "InternetConnect";
    {
        DWORD flags =
            INTERNET_FLAG_CACHE_IF_NET_FAIL |
            INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
            INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
            INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION |
            INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
            INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE |
            INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD |
            INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE |
            INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
        char url[100];
        sprintf(url, "http://%s:%d/", remoteHost, remotePort);
        hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "GET", "connect.html", "HTTP/1.0", url, 0, flags, 0);
        if (!hRequest) return "HttpOpenRequest";
    }
    {
        DWORD flags=0;
        DWORD bufferLength = sizeof(flags);
        if (!InternetQueryOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &flags, &bufferLength)) {
            return "InternetQueryOption";
        }
        flags |= (SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION);
        if (!InternetSetOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &flags, sizeof(flags))) {
            return "InternetSetOption";
        }
    }
    if (!HttpSendRequest(hRequest, 0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        return "HttpSendRequest";
    } else {
        char buffer[4];
        DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
        if (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, &buffer, &bufferSize, NULL)) {
        return "HttpQueryInfo";
        } else if (atoi(buffer) != 200) {
            return "status code";
        }
    }
    {
        INTERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO idsi;
        DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(idsi);
        if (!InternetQueryOption(hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO, &idsi, &bufferSize)) {
            return "InternetQueryOption";
        } else if (idsi.Socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            /* This is always the case on our Windows 7 platform, why? */
            return "invalid socket";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    const char *error = _connect();
    if (error) {
        printf("ERROR: %s (%d)\n", error, GetLastError());
    } else {
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[From MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/option-flags)

INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO 67

Retrieves an INTERNET_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO structure that contains data about a specified HTTP Request. This flag is used by InternetQueryOption.

**Windows 7:  This option is no longer supported.**

Answer (score 2):

Is the HTTP request using keep-alives?  If not, then my guess would be that WinInet under Win7 is invalidating the socket handle after closing it when receiving the server's response, whereas XP does not invalidate the socket.

Comment: The flag INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION is set and with a sniffer, I get the same HTTP request headers, among which I have 'Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive'. However, on XP, the TCP connection remains alive but on 7, the client sends a FIN when the SSL handshake is complete. So you are right, I get an INVALID_SOCKET because the TCP connection is terminated, but I don't see why it is so on 7, and it remains connected on XP.

Comment: Is the request using HTTP 1.0 or 1.1? Is there a `Connection: keep-alive` header for the non-proxy portion of the connection if HTTP 1.0 is being used?  Do the response's `Proxy-Connection` and `Connection` headers also say `keep-alive`?

Comment: The request uses HTTP 1.0. I cannot check if the `Connection: keep-alive` is sent since it seems encrypted by the SSL layer when I look at the Wireshark logs. The proxy response is `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established` with no header sent back. The HTTP messages are the same regardless the client is running on XP or on 7. However on 7, after the proxy response (status 200), after the encrypted handshake, my client sends some application SSLv3 encrypted data (the GET request?), then it receives some application data back from the server, then the connection is shutdown (TCP FIN sent by client).

Comment: That behavior does suggest that either `Connection: keep-alive` is not being sent in the request OR `Connection: close` is being sent in the response. You are using WinInet, so you can use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) to view SSL-encrypted HTTP traffic, as it auto-installs itself as a WinInet proxy so it sees outbound data before SSL encrypts it, and inbound data after SSL decrypts it.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working. The thing is that wininet puts the connection back into a pool once the server response has been received. Hence, the socket is not anymore associated to the session when I ask for it. So, I ended up using HttpSendRequestEx() to have wininet believe that I am not yet done sending the request. This way wininet keeps the connection associated with my session, and when I get the socket, I parse the response myself and keep going. Thanks for your tips and your time anyway. It was very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure your project is not compiling for unicode? In case it does you need to change your `char` declaration to `wchar_t` and prefix your constants with `L` like:

```
const wchar_t * pszTmp = L"hello world";
```