# Longpolling with WinAPI's InternetReadFile()

Tags: c, http, winapi, long-polling, wininet

I'm writing a cross platform app. I need to get data from a longpoll url.

On Mac/Linux I can use curl, `curl_easy_perform()` takes care of everything automatically.

On Windows I have to use native api. The code below works fine for normal urls, but when I try to use a longpoll url, it just quits immediately (`nr_read == 0`) instead of waiting until there's new data:

```
...
   flags =
 INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |
 INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID |
 INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP |
 INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH |
 INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
 INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES  |  
 INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION |
 INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD 
 INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
...

HINTERNET internet = InternetOpenA(user_agent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET connect = InternetConnectA(internet, host, port, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
HINTERNET request = HttpOpenRequest(connect, req_typ, path, "HTTP/1.1", NULL, NULL, flags, NULL);


#define BUF_MAX 1024
TCHAR buf[BUF_MAX + 1];
int nr_read = 0;
while (1) {
     int ok = InternetReadFile(request, buf, BUF_MAX, &nr_read);
     if (!ok) {
             puts("not ok");
             break;
     }
     if (nr_read == 0) {
             puts("nr read 0, breaking");
             break;
     }
     buf[nr_read] = 0;
     printf("buf='%s'\n", buf);
     nr_read = 0;
}
```

Response headers I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 101
Switching Protocols
upgrade: websocket
connection: upgrade
```

After the handshake, libcurl keeps piping websocket data (which I can manually process), but `InternetReadFile()` just quits.

I send an http request with

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: key
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

the server answers with the headers above and then libcurl gives me `{"type": "hello"}` and so on, but `InternetReadFile()` just exits.

Comment: Before you call InternetReadFile or any Windows Socket/Wininet function. Can you verify that you're calling WSAStartup ? And InternetOpenUrl/HttpOpenRequest succeeded.

Comment: I had no WSAStartup(), adding it didn't help. InternetConnectA() and HttpOpenRequest() errors are handled.

Comment: I have a feeling there must be an internet flag to enable long polling...

Comment: @Nina You don't need to call `WSAStartup()` when using WinInet, only when using Winsock directly

Comment: After looking at curl's code I now have a feeling that I have to implement long polling on the client manually...

Comment: @Alex WinInet only handles 1 request at a time. When `nr_read == 0`, that means the current request has finished without error. In [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/), The server will not respond until it has data to give, or a timeout has occured in which case a timeout reply is sent. You then have to make a new request to keep receiving new data. Also, make sure you are using the `INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION` flag when making each request.

Comment: But long polling is about having only 1 request, not making multiple requests. It'd be trivial to implement with sockets, but I need https, so I hoped wininet has the same support of long polling that libcurl does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, missed a part of your answer. The server indeed only responds only when it has data to give, but in this case nr_read is 0 right away, and the entire loop exits.

Comment: @Alex that is not how long polling works. See the link I provided. Once a response has been sent with one piece of new data (or timeout), you have to send a new request to get the next piece of new data. In your case, what kind of data is your `buf` actually receiving? If nothing, then the server is not sending anything in the response body. Are you checking the HTTP response code and headers for errors? Use `HttpQueryInfo()` for that. I bet the server is not sending the kind of response you are expecting, and you are not handling it.

Comment: Bad wording from me. In any case, my code above should work with long polling, but it doesn't. I'm using the keep connection flag.

Comment: What I want to do is to somehow make `InternetReadFile()` wait until there's data, not return nothing immediately.

Comment: I've added the calls to `HttpOpenRequest()`, `InternetConnectA()`, and `InternetOpenA()`, maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the response from the server is ok, and it's handled by the linux version correctly. These are the headers I'm getting: `HEADERS HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
upgrade: websocket
connection: upgrade`

Comment: That is not HTTP long polling at all. You are initiating a [WebSocket](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) connection instead, something WinInet does not support. WebSocket starts out as HTTP, but after the handshake is complete, it is not HTTP anymore. So it makes perfect sense that the server's response body would be empty, that is how WebSocket works. Once your loop has ended, you need to handle the WebSocket protocol separately.  Microsoft has a [different API for handling WebSocket](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/websock/web-socket-protocol-component-api-portal).

Comment: Yes, I'm handling websocket protocol on my own with libcurl, so I assumed I could do the same with WinInet. The websocket api only works on Windows 8/10. Thanks for your help, I now see that libcurl was handling the websocket protocol. I have to figure out how to do that manually with WinInet.

Comment: You can't use WinInet to handle WebSocket once the HTTP handshake is complete. Prior to Win7, you could get the raw `SOCKET` from the WinInet session via [`InternetQueryOption(INTERNET_OPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_SOCKET_INFO)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wininet/ns-wininet-internet_diagnostic_socket_info), and then use the Winsock API on that socket. But that option was removed from WinInet in Win7. You are best off using a 3rd party WebSocket library, or write your own WebSocket implementation using Winsock directly, with SChannel or OpenSSL for SSL/TLS encryption.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. I now understand how ridiculous it is to try to handle websockets with an HTTP library (although libcurl magically handles it somehow). Can you create a short answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I would be very surprised if libcurl actually supports WebSockets.  The handshake, maybe, since that is plain HTTP/S.  libcurl does has [`CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY.html) and [`CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET.html) options for dealing with situations where the application needs to take over communications after libcurl has established a connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau libcurl doesn't support websockets, but after the handshake, it keeps piping data (which I can manually process), unlike `InternetReadFile`. That's what I need `InternetReadFile()` to do. I send an http request with `Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: key
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13`, the server answers with `HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< upgrade: websocket
< connection: upgrade
< sec-websocket-accept: [...]
< X-Via: [...]` and then libcurl it gives me `{"type": "hello"}` and so on, but `InternetReadFile()` just exits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055054/trying-to-get-socket-from-wininet-http-connection has a solution in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Anders. That looks interesting. I now have to figure out how to use `HttpSendRequestEx` since it doesn't accept headers/data arguments, and also how to make it work without going to the sockets level.

Comment: @Alex look at `HttpAddRequestHeaders()`. But, if you really want the behavior of libcurl, then why not simply USE libcurl? It is available for Windows. It is not shipped with the OS, but you can compile it statically into your app, or use it as a DLL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using libcurl :)

..